# PHP прокинуть соединеине с базой данных в другой файл

Tags: php, база-данных, medoo

Собственно есть несколько разных файлов PHP с различным функционалом, часть которого повторяется практически в каждом файле, например: авторизаиция, соединение с базой данных.

```
if ( empty( $_POST['api_id'] ) || empty( $_POST['viewer_id'] ) || empty( $_POST['auth_key'] ) ) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
    echo 'One or more params is wrong';
    exit;
}

$api_id = $_POST['api_id'];
$viewer_id = $_POST['viewer_id'];
$auth_key = $_POST['auth_key'];
include('api_secret.php');

$md5result = md5($api_id.'_'.$viewer_id.'_'.$api_secret);

if ( $md5result !== $auth_key ) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 401 Unauthorized");
    echo 'Access denied';
    exit;
}
```

Данный блок повторяется в каждом файле и его приходится каждый раз прописывать.

Или вот еще:

```
require "Medoo.php";
use Medoo\Medoo;

$db = new Medoo([
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'db_name',
    'server' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
]);
```

Этот блок тоже повторяется везде. Пробовал вынести его отдельным файлом и includ/require, на примере с `include('api_secret.php')`, но почему-то не работает. Подозреваю, что из-за `use`.

Вопрос: как можно реализовать это в виде библиотек/функций/чего-угодно, лишь бы избавиться от избыточного кода и подключать в каждом файле?

Answer (score 0):

Вынес все в отдельные файлы и завернул в функции:

```
function authUser( $api_id, $viewer_id, $auth_key ) {
if ( empty( api_id ) || empty( viewer_id ) || empty( auth_key ) ) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
    echo 'One or more params is wrong';
    exit;
}
include('api_secret.php');

$md5result = md5($api_id.'_'.$viewer_id.'_'.$api_secret);

if ( $md5result !== $auth_key ) {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 401 Unauthorized");
    echo 'Access denied';
    exit;
}
}
```

В основном файле подключаю и вызываю так:

```
require('auth.php');
authUser( $_POST[ 'api_id' ], $_POST[ 'viewer_id' ], $_POST[ 'auth_key' ] );
```

С БД примерно то же самое, только в конце возвращаю переменную $db

```
require "Medoo.php";
use Medoo\Medoo;

function connectToDB() {
$db = new Medoo([
    'database_type'=>'mysql',
    'database_name'=>'db_name',
    "server"=>'127.0.0.1',
    'username'=>'username',
    'password'=>'password',
    'charset'=>'utf8'
]);

return $db;
}

$db = connectToDB();
```

В основном файле подключаю так:

```
require('db_connect.php');
```